# Getting weird noise when using an attenuator cable

Tags: audio, cable

I'm using a -25Db attenuator cable ([this one](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/767986-REG/Whirlwind_WHH4NL3_5_WHH4NL3_5_Line_to_Microphone.html)) to connect an audio mixer to my camera. Now, I've tested the cable by connecting my DAP to the camera, and it works just fine. But when I connect the attenuator cable, even without an audio mixer plugged-in, I hear background noise. When I turn on the audio mixer but don't have any input sources for it, the noise is even louder. When I connect a radiomic to the mixer, the loud noise is still there, coupled with the audio from the microphone.

Can someone help me figure out what's going on here? Am I somehow using an attenuator cable incorrectly? I doubt it's faulty considering that connecting a DAP to my camera results in a good, clean signal and no noise on the line.

Comment: What is a DAP??

Comment: did you check if the input volume is somewhere in a decent range? Or is this auto level control? What camera are you talking about?

Comment: @HansMeiser DAP = digital audio player. There is a level control, I've tried going up and down, the noise is still there. The camera is Sony a7R II.

Comment: What kind of mixer do you use and did you try to connect it with a regular (non attenuator) cable?